# Alternative to on change event for selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, custom-data-attribute

I have multiple options that a user can choose from. In my actual code they can only choose one option at a time (for some reason it isn't working in the snippet). What I am doing is getting the price from the data attribute and writing that into a different section of the page.

I believe my issue is stemming from the `change` function. If a user deselects their option and clicks on another one, it takes both of those prices...or if they click and unclick the same option. So instead of just having one price, it may do this:

$13, $13, $15, $17, $13

How can I just display the active checked data price?

Please disregard the error for `calcTotalPrice()` function. It is not relevant to my issue. Thanks

[jsfiddle if you prefer to look at that.](https://jsfiddle.net/qhkz8rvo/)

```js
var calPrice = [];
var limitCal = 1;
$('.calendar-check').on('change', function() {
  if (!this.checked || $('.calendar-check:checked').length <= limitCal) {
    $('.calendar-check:checked').each(function() {
      calPrice.push($(this).data('cal-price'));
    });
    $('#pg-price-review').html("$ " + calPrice);
    calcTotalPrice();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
A
<input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" data-cal-price="13" id="cal-glance" value="At-A-Glance Calendar"> 
B
<input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" data-cal-price="15" id="cal-glance" value="At-A-Glance Calendar"> 
C
<input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" data-cal-price="17" id="cal-glance" value="At-A-Glance Calendar">

<p id="pg-price-review" class="small-description margin15"></p>
```

Comment: Why don't you use radio buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to replace selected element with attribute value and use [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to convert array to string. At the end write string in html.

```
$('.calendar-check').on('change', function() {
  var str = $('.calendar-check:checked').map(function() {
    return "$" + $(this).data('cal-price');
  }).toArray().join(" ");
  $('#pg-price-review').html(str);
});
```

```js
$('.calendar-check').on('change', function() {
  var str = $('.calendar-check:checked').map(function() {
    return "$" + $(this).data('cal-price');
  }).toArray().join(" ");
  $('#pg-price-review').html(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
A<input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" data-cal-price="13" id="cal-glance" value="At-A-Glance Calendar"> 
B<input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" data-cal-price="15" id="cal-glance" value="At-A-Glance Calendar"> 
C<input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" data-cal-price="17" id="cal-glance" value="At-A-Glance Calendar">
<p id="pg-price-review" class="small-description margin15"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you. Only now my total price function isn't working. The function is: `function calcTotalPrice() {
         var totalPrice = calPrice.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0) + tpPrice.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
         $('#package-review-total').html("$ " + totalPrice);
     }` ...... see updated original fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/qhkz8rvo/6/

Comment: @Paul Because my solution is different with your solution, i changed the `calcTotalPrice()` . See https://jsfiddle.net/jwjxka0L/

Comment: It also take a variable `tpPrice` from this change function `$('.tp-pack-check').on('change', function () {`. Are you able to nest change functions?

Comment: @Paul `tpPrice` array allway is empty and is unused in code.

Comment: It is unused in my example I showed, but it is a vital part of my actual code. I basically have two sections. Cal and TP. Both with options that have values, in which the `totalPrice` calculates the two. Sorry for not noting this.. I just didn't think it would disturb the total price code.

Comment: @Paul The `tpPrice` and `totalPrice` has some value

Comment: Here is an updated version of your fiddle. I added in the tp part how I had it. https://jsfiddle.net/jwjxka0L/1/ you will see that is doesn't work in my traditional way.

Comment: Because second part of your code doesn't work. However i changed it. See https://jsfiddle.net/jwjxka0L/2/

Comment: Perfect, sorry that took so much! I thought the only issue would have just been the change function. I appreciate all of the help!